# Postgres database size much bigger than tablespaces on filesystem

Tags: postgresql, size, tablespace

I have a Postgres 8.3 instance with tablespaces totalling on about 74G. This is fine.

But if I ask postgres how big my database is, I get a (unexpected) large answer: 595 GB.

This seems very strange. Disk I/O tests on the system are in the 'normal' range, but queries are slower than they used to be.

Is this corruption of the database? Or are there ways to 'fix' this oddity?

[Edit]
I check the tablespace size by the os:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/data/tblspaces/du -c -h
74G total
```

All tablespaces are there

I check te database size like this:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('database'))
```

[Edit2]

I also checked the entire /usr/local/pgsql/ dir. It is 76 G

And I ran this query:

```
select
  tablename
, pg_relation_size(tablename)
, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(tablename) ) as relsize
, pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(tablename) ) as disksize
, pg_total_relation_size(tablename)
from pg_tables where schemaname <> 'information_schema'
order by 2 desc
```

Which returned 'normal' relationsizes, none of which exceeded the disksize.

Comment: How did you check the database size? And the tablespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a corruption issue. Full restore of a backup fixed the problem

Comment: I just had this exact problem. On 3 computers a db was 12gb. On another it was 96gb.  A full backup and restore totally fixed it.  Still have no idea what's going on but this totally works

Answer (score 1):

The size of the tablespace can be checked by using:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_tablespace_size('name of tablespace'));
```

It looks like your database didn't store all it's objects (tables, indexes, etc.) in your specific tablespace but also another (default?) tablespace. Check pg_class and pg_tablespace, something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM pg_class 
    JOIN pg_tablespace ON reltablespace = pg_tablespace.oid
WHERE
    spcname <> 'name of tablespace';
```

Comment: As said in the post above, all tablespaces in the database are stored on the OS in one directory, and the content of that directory are a lot smaller than the database size.

Comment: Did you actually check if all database objects are stored in these tablespaces? Some objects might be on the default tablespace, like the TOAST tables and indexes.

Comment: Tablespaces on different volumes are implemented as symlinks in that folder so won't count against the size

Answer (score 0):

It sounds so strange!  How did you check the database size and the tablespace size?
may be your database locate in different tablespaces.

--to get the databasesize
mydb=> select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('mydb'));

### pg_size_pretty

214 MB
(1 row)

--to show all the tablespace
connect your db,and type the following commond
\db

Comment: Strange indeed. I verified the tablespaces from the \db with the ones on the os, they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you vacuumed the DB recently?  That can potentially have dramatic effects, particularly if there's a lot of churn on larger tables.

Also, how big is the result of a pg_dump?